# Detect inventory change

Tags: magento

How can I detect when a product's inventory level reaches 0 or it's status is changed to "Out of Stock" by Magento (not necessarily by the user)? I looked for an event, but I don't see one. Is my only choice to override the Stock_Item model?

Comment: look again theres multiple events for that :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Look in `app/code/core/Mage/CatalogInventory/Model/Stock/Item.php` and notice that the $_eventPrefix is set to `cataloginventory_stock_item`.  That means that you can use the generic Object Saving events detailed in [this blog post](http://masteringmagento.com/2010/10/complete-events-list-for-magento-community-1-4-1-0/) to register an Observer, e.g. `cataloginventory_stock_item_save_after` and inspect the values of the object.

You will almost never need to override the model when you use the generic events.

Comment: @Benubird Here's the link via archive.org: http://web.archive.org/web/20101020121221/http://masteringmagento.com/2010/10/complete-events-list-for-magento-community-1-4-1-0/