# Magento 1.6, An event for when stock levels change?

Tags: magento

I need to know the name of an event which is dispatched whenever stock levels change for a product.

So far I've been able to use cataloginventory_stock_item_save_after, however this only seems to be dispatched when I make a change to stock levels in the backend.

If I create an order in the backend, stock levels go down, but this event is not dispatched.

I'm not sure about the which event to use when someone orders a product on the frontend either.

I'm using magento 1.6.

Thanks in advance for any help I may receive.

Answer (score 0):

You could always see what events are fired by doing as Alan Storm suggests here in his answer to this question:
[Is there an event for customer account registration in Magento?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2968294/is-there-an-event-for-customer-account-registration-in-magento/2968705#2968705)

It will give you all of the events that are fired when you perform an action...just make sure you only turn it on/off when you actually require it or you will end up with a large number of events to trawl through

Comment: Thank you, I had already tried this and there seemed to be a massive number of events fired, even when turning on/off just before and after performing the action.

There were none there that looked obvious, many looked like they would be called in other parts of the site.

Comment: I'm using version 1.6.1 and just ran the following to see if I could find an event that is suitable...I could not find the event you mentioned:

    find . -name "*.php" | xargs -L10 grep -n -A 6 -B 6 "dispatchEvent" .> events.txt

I run this from the root of my magento directory. I found this at this blog: http://www.edmondscommerce.co.uk/magento/magento-events-cheat-sheet-grep-works-for-any-version/

Answer (score 0):

Look at the answer Jonathan Day gave me here: [Detect inventory change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7376927/detect-inventory-change)

Look in `app/code/core/Mage/CatalogInventory/Model/Stock/Item.php` and notice that the `$_eventPrefix` is set to `cataloginventory_stock_item`. That means that you can use the generic Object Saving events detailed in [this blog post](http://masteringmagento.com/2010/10/complete-events-list-for-magento-community-1-4-1-0/) to register an Observer, e.g. `cataloginventory_stock_item_save_after` and inspect the values of the object.

Comment: Just noticed that you referenced this event in your question.  However, that is the event I ended up using and it works fine in the frontend.